# Removal of location names

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, esa

I am using the FireCCI51: MODIS Fire_cci Burned Area Pixel Product, Version 5.1 dataset on Google Earth Engine and wondered whether there was a way of removing place names from my image or overlaying them so the data doesn't cover them?

I have tried the `map.remove` feature but it does not seem to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I found it as an option under "satellite".

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [tour].  Well done on solving your own problem!  Please [edit] your answer to include details of the option you found and how to use it - this helps future users that come across the same problem that you did.